# Get Xml Content="{Binding XPath=...}" in event handler "(sender as Button).Content"

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Faced a problem. The button context uses XML file tags (**dynamic** resource 
 `DataContext="{DynamicResource XmlResource}"`). Everything is fine, I get Content on the buttons correctly ("Name 1", "Name 2", ...). Next, in the mouse event, I want to assign the value of the button content to the variable `contentText` and display it on the console. However, I did not receive the expected. I received either `System.Xml.XmlElement` or empty string.

```
// XML
<Root>
    <Name1>Name 1</Name1>
    <Name2>Name 2</Name2>
    ...
</Root>

// XAML
<Grid DataContext="{DynamicResource XmlResource}">
    <Button MouseEnter="ButtonEnter" Content="{Binding XPath=Root/Name1}" />
    <Button MouseEnter="ButtonEnter" Content="{Binding XPath=Root/Name2}" />
...
</Grid>

// C#
private void ButtonEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Version 1
    string contentText = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(contentText); // Output value "System.Xml.XmlElement"

    // Version 2
    string contentText = (sender as Button).Content as string;
    Console.WriteLine(contentText); // Output empty string

    // Version 3
    string contentText = sender.GetType().GetProperty("Content").GetValue(sender, null).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(contentText); // Output value "System.Xml.XmlElement"
}
```

How do I attach button contents ("Name 1", "Name 2", ...) to `contentText` variable? Maybe I can’t get the exact value, as a dynamic resource `DataContext="{DynamicResource XmlResource}"`? thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output value "System.Xml.XmlElement" means that Content is XmlElement. Cast Content to concrete type and get properties instead of getting its string representation:

```
var contentElement = (sender as Button).Content as System.Xml.XmlElement;
Console.WriteLine(contentElement.InnerText);
```